# Index of wp-admin webiste home page open but wp-admin not open

Tags: wordpress, indexing, error-handling, cpanel, custom-wordpress-pages

Facing this error any solution

[image]

Comment: Please add some description. What you try and whats expected output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched in google:site: your URL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).